# How to loop a query in a dataset?

Tags: coldfusion

I have some javascript and query that I would like to use together.
How can I make the dataset use the query columns not the hardcore data.

I know I will have to probably use loop and  cfscript since using js will give me errors.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Create a DataSet (allows two way data-binding)
  var items = new vis.DataSet([
    {id: 1, content: 'item 1', start_time: '2014-04-20'},
    {id: 2, content: 'item 2', start_time: '2014-04-14'},
    {id: 3, content: 'item 3', start_time: '2014-04-18'}
  ]);
    // Configuration for the Timeline
  var options = {};
  // Create a Timeline
  var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, options);
</script>
<cfquery  name="getimeline">
SELECT content,start_time
FROM timeline
</cfquery>
```

Comment: A cleaner route would be to pull in your data using AJAX and JSON. But in the case basically put your cfquery above your js then do a cfoutput with the query attribute and insert your column variables as normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach should get you started.

```
<cfquery name="getTimeLine">
SELECT content,start_time
FROM timeline
</cfquery>

<script>
var items = new vis.DataSet([
<cfoutput query="getTimeLine">
{id: #currentrow#, content: '#content#', start_time: '#dateformat(start_time, "yyyy-mm-dd")#'},
</cfquery>
]);
```

Intentionally left out in order to make you do some work, is the part where you exclude the comma from the last item.

Comment: great, i figure out the comma part too